# Charging UserPoints for flagging a node with Rules in PHP

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I am trying to charge points for flagging a node with Rules in PHP, an I am using the following code.

```
 //Get variables and load user.
$uid = [userpoints-transaction:user:uid];
$account = user_load($uid);

// Check the user has enough points.
if ($loaded_points > 10) {

  // DON'T KNOW HOW TO TAKE 10 POINTS.

  // Flag a node.
  $flag = flag_get_flag('purchase') or die('no "purchase" flag defined');
  $flag->flag('flag', $node->nid);
  // Search for the newly created flagging entity.
  $flag = flag_get_user_flags('node', $node->nid);

  foreach ($flag as $flagging_object) {
    $flagging_id = $flagging_object->flagging_id;
  }

  // Load the entity found and create or update a field value.
  $flagging = entity_load_single('flagging', $flagging_id);
  $flagging->purchase['und'][0]['value'] = 'DONT KNOW DEFAULT VALUE OF FLAGGING';

  // Save the updated flagging entity object.
  entity_save('flagging', $flagging);
}

drupal_set_message($msg);
```

I don't know how to charge them 10 points and what the default value is when flagging a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply want to grant 10 userpoints to a user after flagging a node, you're making things way to complicated! This can be done without custom coding at all. Here's what you have to do:

1. Create a new rule.
2. Add an event "A node has been flagged, under YOUR_FLAG".
3. Add an action "Grant points to a user" and give it an amount of 10.
4. Done!